# "Maximal Commutative subset"

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking at a proof of Frobenius Theorem, but I can't understand what is meant by the term "Maximal commutative subset." The relevant part of my link is in the proof of (1). The author supposes that F is a subspace of D of maximum dimension that is commutative, and goes on to show that F is a maximal commutative subspace. I don't really know what either of these things could mean.

I'm assuming that "F is a subspace of D of maximum dimension that is commutative and contains R(d)" means that F is a subspace of D containing R(d) and that is commutative, and then has as high a dimension as possible while retaining the previously stated properties. 
Link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17606191/proof.gif

Could anyone clarify? Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is called a maximal commutative subset if for every commutative subset $L$ containing $F$ we have $L=F$. In the proof this is used for $L=F+Rx$. On the other hand, there is the maximal dimension of a commutative subspace in an algebra. This means exactly what it says: take the maximum dimension of all possible commutative subspaces.

Comment: Oh ok, so you could have two distinct maximal commutative subsets? If I take the commutative subspace with maximum dimension, then there could be other commutative subspaces not contained in it? Thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: There can also be more than one commutative subspace of maximal dimension.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot!